# How can a script from a local machine can work based on Firefox's flag

Tags: firefox

Is there a simple way for Firefox to send a simple flag value to the local machine, so a program inside the local machine can react upon the flag.

I have put so much effort in cookies, extensions and even Javascript read/write file .. all of it failed. i just wanted a way that the Firefox can give signal to local machine. That's all.

For example, I create a simple extension that monitors a certain URL. Then, when the URL is visited, Firefox will signal something or set a flag. I will code a simple script to read the flag and do other things..

I am on Linux platform.

Comment: I still do not quite understand your requirements. Is it any URL or the scripts at those URLs will read the flag? Sounds like it's either using cookies or FF extension.

Comment: I think this looks like breaking end-user safety.

You may not be allowed to send informations to local programs from firefox.

Comment: O.K.W., the script is located on my local machine. So as my sample webpage. All is located on one single machine. I tried cookies before, but it seems that I have problem to read cookies.sqlite which is locked during FF is running.

Amaud, this may seems like breaking a security design, but its not my main intention. This work just as a demonstration on a local machine :)

Answer (score 1):

you can write to a file on disk,  the application on your local machine can monitor for this file existence and act upon it.

I also suggest that the "other"  application rename the file as soon as it find it so firefox can single again.

see [here](http://simon-jung.blogspot.com/2007/10/firefox-extension-file-io.html) about Firefox file i/o  using java script

Comment: hi Alon. yes, I have tried the code. But I got error at this line:

netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");

I says that I done have access. I could not find a way to solve it.

Comment: you have to configure file permissions : http://tiddlywiki.org/wiki/How_To/Firefox_Per-File_Permissions

Comment: Ok, I'm giving it another try. Before this I used this below line:

netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");

Comment: I have tried what you suggested. Added the permissions to prefs.js. But I got this error when running the extension:

Error: Permission denied for <file://> to get property XPCComponents.classes

Need help..

Answer (score 0):

Try using Applets to access the clients machine, this doesn't limit you to use Firefox other browsers as well.

Comment: I thought Firefox blocks all communication coming from inside the browser.

Comment: Im trying with java applet right now. but when run in firefox, it says error:

"caught security exception".


why?

Comment: it seems like this is a browser configuration issue with applets, check if applets has the appropriate rights.